# How can I make flow type refinement stick?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can I unwrap maybe type like swift optional types, something like this:

```
guard let certainVar = optionalVar else {
  return;
}
```

The reason I ask is that refinement are often lost, i want a way to make them stick like we can do in swift. It is a bit awkward to do that as far as I know, maybe something like this:

```
let certainVar;
if (maybeVar) {
  certainVar = maybeVar; // must save that certain value now before
                         // the refinement gets invalidated
} else {
  return;
}
```

The disadvantages for this approach:

1. certainVar and maybeVar can't have the same name
2. Very verbose, I would like to do this in a lot of places

Comment: Just put `if (!optionalVar) { return; }`. After this line `optionalVar` has unwrapped type. Other option (is you really want another name for certainVar): `let certainVar; if (!(certainVar = optionalVar)) return;`

Comment: Instead of assigning to a non-maybe var, why not just put the dependent code in the conditional? `if (maybeVar) { /* ... do stuff with maybeVar */ }`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of them quite work in my case, the rest of the logic dealing with maybeVar have function calls that will cause refinement invalidation: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations

However, the `let certainVar; if (!(certainVar = optionalVar)) return;` sounds like a reasonable alternative, albeit not the most readable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const`:

```
if (maybeVar) {
    const certainConst = maybeVar;
    ...
```

function calls will not cause refinement invalidation of a constant